# Can "scale" be used for any purpose?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

[Can it be used for any purpose?](http://www.google.co.id/imgres?imgurl=http://38.media.tumblr.com/1e5ba3703b2c8421f4c52a25721f5eee/tumblr_inline_mv6ic3nS5g1spkw60.jpg&imgrefurl=http://timbangandigitalkenko.tumblr.com/&h=279&w=369&tbnid=K2ze56H7I1F2IM:&q=timbangan&docid=U4LaRBGOSr7T9M&ei=U6pdVsnaPNaLuATjpJ6oBw&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwiJ0IDC67rJAhXWBY4KHWOSB3UQMwguKA0wDQ)

Please check the image.
What is the name of such tool that is used to weigh compost and fertilizer?

Comment: Do you mean can a scale weigh anything? "For any purpose" is very unclear. It could be asking something as crazy as if you could use a scale as a hammer.

Comment: *Scale* is the generic term today for any device which measures weight, but there are scores if not hundreds of sorts of scale. What sort of scale you use will depend on a number of factors such as what mechanism is employed, what volume and weight will be measured, what form the substance measured arrives in, how the substance is delivered to the scale, how precise a measurement you require, and so forth. There may be specialty scales for some substances, but I'd be surprised if there were scales specifically designed for measuring fertilizer as opposed to, say, sand or bricks or grain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [**digital weighing scale**](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=digital+weighing+scale&espv=2&biw=2051&bih=965&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHvKmv77rJAhUJdz4KHT2eAyYQ_AUIBigB&dpr=0.67). The word 'weighing scale' is a general term for machines/instruments which measure weight. Note that the word [**scale**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scale) means:

> an instrument or machine for weighing

Hope you'd clarify what does the line, 'for any purpose' mean? Do you mean, for any instrument/s?

Comment: for weighing fertilizer.

Comment: As long as you are measuring weight, you may use the term.

Comment: Also, please do not accept answers quickly. There may be other better answers/opinions later (at least give it a day or two). Welcome to ELL!